# Doesn't work regular expression for domain with hyphens

Tags: bash, shell, regex, shell-scripting, regular-expressions

I have some smart script, that check name of server and get domain name.
For example, i have name of server: example.ru01. I need to get: example.ru
My scipt:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=example.com01
echo $hostname
reg0="\(\(\w*\.[a-z]*\)\|\(\w*\.[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\)\)"
domain=`expr match $hostname $reg0`
echo $domain
```

It is ok. in output i have:

```
example.com01
example.com
```

But, in my infrastructure, i have some domains with hyphens. For example: test-test.com01. But it doesn't working in my script. How to resolve this problem ? Please help. I made some changes in my regular expression, like this:

```
\(\(\w*\.[a-z_-]*\)\|\(\w*\.[a-z_-]*\.[a-z_-]*\)\)
```

But it doesn't work. Where i have error ? Please help. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your regular expression is that you tell it that it must first match your string with zero to infinity amounts of `\w` which "Matches any word character including underscore", followed by a literal dot `.`. (`\w*\.`)

in the case of `test-test.com01` it does not match because of the hyphen, so  if you change it to match also `-` then it will work the way you want it to:

```
\(\([a-z_-]*\.[a-z_-]*\)\|\([a-z_]*\.[a-z_-]*\.[a-z_-]*\)\)
      ^ replace \w            ^ replace \w
```

There are several ways to improve this regular expression but IMO the amount of time you should put into making a good one is proportional to the complexity of the text you parse.

Comment: i have written this: "\(\([a-z_-]*\)\|\([a-z_-]*\.[a-z_-]*\)\)"

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers only occur at the end of your hostnames, you also could just remove all numbers from the end. Which I think is easier to read and maintain.

```
hostname=example.com01
echo $hostname
domain=$(echo $hostname | sed -e 's/[0-9]*$//g')
echo domain
```

Comment: that's very nice. but in this case, i need to use regular expressions. for example, i have hosts, like that: test-test.comNY01

Comment: In that case you would have to extend the regular expression to match `[A-Z]` as well. Not sure how much diversity your hostnames provide, I thought it would be easier to just cut off the last part.

Comment: Or just use hostname=${hostname%[0-9][0-9]}